# WebView video not playing in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-webview, android-video-player

After including `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file, `WebView` video playing
perfectly in android 4.0 and above, But not in android 2.3.3 .

what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` is supported from Android 3.0 and above. But If you add it in your `AndroidManifest` and your `targetSDK` is API-11 or later. Apk will run on Android 2.3 but `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` flag will be ignored.

For playing video in Android 2.3 you will have to open it in Video View. Read the below link for more detail :

http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/31646/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android/

Comment: Don't think so.. Whatever solution is given is also nothing but just a hack.

Comment: Detect the url. Override onCustomView() method. open videoview to play video.